# How to use more than one delimiter +JDBC

Tags: sql, jdbc, ant, plsql

I am using jdbc compilations with ant. Now the default delimiter is slash. is there any way i can use more than one delimiter. like both ; and /

```
<sql driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.184.133.133:1521:SUPP"
userid="${UsernameB}"
password="${PasswordB}"
onerror="continue"
delimitertype="row"
delimiter="/"
keepformat="yes">
```

Answer (score 1):

Now without changing something.  You could make a copy of the task and change it to do what you want.  That's not the simplest solution though.

I recommend you use Ant to:

1. make a copy of the file
2. turn all the semicolons into slashes in the copy
3. load the copy using the sql task